# Connected component of $\{(x_1,...,x_n) \; | \; x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2-x_n^2 \neq 0\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness, path-connected

The question is in the title, actually for $n=2$, it's okay, for $n=3$, I thought that :

$\{(x_1,...,x_n) \; | \; x_1^2+x_2^2-{x_{3}}^2 < 0 \}, \{(x_1,...,x_n) \; | \; x_1^2+x_2^2-{x_{3}}^2 > 0 \}$ are the connected component.

Actually, for $n \geq 4$, I have the impression that $\{(x_1,...,x_n) \; | \; x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2-x_n^2 < 0 \}, \{(x_1,...,x_n) \; | \; x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2-x_n^2 > 0 \}$ are the connected component, cause each are open and closed, but I need to prove that it's connected.

Anyone could help me, please ?

Thank you !

Comment: "I thought that" - what makes you think so?

Comment: The two sets are closed and open. So, for sure there is at least two connex components. And each set seems connected, and even path connected, but I didn't prove it in an explicit way, that's why I've written "I thought".

Comment: @ChocoSavour $\{(x_1,...,x_n) \; | \; x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2-x_n^2 < 0 \}$ is open but not close.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I meant closed in $\{(x_1,..., x_n) \; | \; x_1^2+x_2^2+...-x_n^2 \neq 0 \}$, for the topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^n$, isn't it ?

Comment: Then you should precise your question saying that you're looking for the connected components for the induced topology. As stated I understood connected components in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net By definition, at least I think it is, if $X$ is a topological space, a set $Y \subset X$ is said connex if $Y$ is connex for the induced topology. So, it's the same, over $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\{ (x_1,...,x_n) \; | \; x_1^2+...-x_n^2 \neq 0 \}$. Do you agree with that ?

Comment: Can you visualize what happens for $n=3$? It shouldn't be that hard, since $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=0$ is a well-known surface. You should get more connected components than you have now. Then try to use geometric intuition to prove that this components are path-connected (this will mean they are also connected).

Answer (score 1):

Let’s note $S_n= \{(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n \; | \; x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2-x_n^2 \neq 0\}$

**Case $n=2$**

$S_2=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 \neq y^2\} =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x \neq y \wedge x \neq -y\}$ has 4 connected components.

**Case $n \ge 3$**

Let’s prove that in that case, $S_n$ has 3 connected components, namely:

$$\begin{aligned}
S_n^+ &= \left\{(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n  \mid  \sqrt{x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2}< x_n\right\}\\
S_n^0 &= \left\{(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n  \mid  -\sqrt{x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2}< x_n < \sqrt{x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2}\right\}\\
S_n^- &= \left\{(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n  \mid  x_n < -\sqrt{x_1^2+...+{x_{n-1}}^2}\right\}
\end{aligned}$$

Those 3 opens are in fact path connected. $S_n^+$ and $S_n^-$ are convex. Following question: [when is the epigraph a convex cone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466231/when-is-the-epigraph-a-convex-cone) is a good basis for the proof.

$S_n^0$ is path connected and therefore connected. Use «  vertical » lines going to the hyperplane $x_n=0$ and one or two segment lines in the hyperplane $x_n=0$, to avoid passing through the origin.